# Intensifiers: Which one intensifies to the highest degree, and which one to the lowest?

Tags: grammar, intensifiers

Here are the examples of adjectival intensification:

> 1. It's quite cold here in March.
> 2. It's pretty cold here in March.
> 3. It's fairly cold here in March.
> 4. It's rather cold here in March.

To me, their meaning seems altogether the same—*It's cold to a slight or medium degree, a little more or a bit less*— but I doubt about *the exact* sameness.

Also, I once came across the *"nice/good and + adjective"* construction, where *nice* and *good* seem to intensify the adjective. So, I'm adding one more example:

> 5. It's nice/good and dry here in July.

To make the question topical for this site, I should explain that it was brought up during one of the numerous wide-ranging discussions on the subtleties of the English language I had a few days ago with an acquaintance of mine. Then, he claimed that all intensifiers, even those in my examples, can be ranked by their strength, and backing his point, he mentioned  a book on adjective intensification he had come across when he studied the English Language at the University in Kazan, Russia in the early 2000s.

After a painstaking search, I came across a link to a book which is unavailable in the place I live in. When I sent [the link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9042005181)  to the man, he  said that the book's title seems familiar to him, but he's not sure.

So, my question is:

Is it true that the intensifiers in the examples can be ranked by their strength?  If it is true, what might be their descending order? If there's no rule for this, is there a customary usage order? Is the last example really proper usage?

Comment: I don't believe any of these is precise enough to allow them to be ranked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's misleading to suggest that words like this can be "ranked" according to any scale that would be broadly accepted.

Comment: The question has been edited. Is it still off-topic?

Comment: Related http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/88014/9161

Comment: Related http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41285/9161

Comment: Related http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24102/9161

Comment: @ColleenV: Thanks awfully for the links. I'm not this good at finding the answers to my questions in the previous posts.

Comment: @Rompey You don't need to say sorry as you didn't know about it. I don't think you can delete this question, either as you have an upvoted answer. Only option is to flag your own question and ask a moderator to delete this question. It's up to you.

Comment: @Rathony: Thanks again, but since you know all the rules, can I mark an answer to the question as "answered" both here and there?

Comment: @Rompey To be honest with you, I have never encountered this kind of situation. But accepting an answer is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order

> kind of
>   **fairly**  *(least)*
>   **pretty**
>   **rather**
>   **quite**  *(most, especially in BrE)*
>   extremely

Context and intonation will also add to the severity of expression.
There will be some grey area crossover between "pretty" and "rather", and depending on context they may be interchangeable.

"Quite" kind of stands alone in your severity list.

When considering the ranking based on attractiveness

> fairly pretty
>   pretty
>   rather pretty
>   quite pretty

the ordering becomes more obvious

Comment: This seems to be the answer to the question, but could you name the source, please? Or is it just the customary usage?

Comment: It's from usage, what makes it a bit clearer is your inclusion of "pretty". If instead you had used "somewhat" or "kind of" (both less than or equal to "fairly") or "extraordinarily" or "very" (both closer to "quite" and "rather") it might change things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. With what you already wrote, for me, it makes the answer complete.

Answer (score 0):

**It's good and dry** is idiomatic in many rural parts of the United States.  This usage is informal, but not as informal as slang.  To my (American) ear, this usage of "good and" does sound like an intensifier.

**It's nice and dry** is also grammatically correct.  To my ear, this usage of "nice and" sounds more like using a second adjective (connected by a conjunction) than an intensifier.

In other words, "It's good and dry here in July" implies that the soil is parched by the end of the month (unless you irrigate).  Whereas, "It's nice and dry here in July" means "It's nice here in July, partly because it is dry here in July".

Comment: In England "nice and _adjective_" is well-established, and it is a sort of intensifier: I would paraphrase it as "nicely _adjective_", i.e. it has a connotation of approval as well as intensity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the comment. Part of the question is answered.